# System error android sqlite insert

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to build a sqlite database. It has 2800 entries in them. When i try to insert, it takes a minute or so and later gives the system error message. The respective codes are given below.

In the create database java file,

```
ContentValues cv4 = new ContentValues();    
public long createVariantEntry(String varid, String makeid, String modelid, String varname, String posteddate) {        
    cv4.put(VARIANT_ID, varid);
    cv4.put(VARIANT_MAKE_ID, makeid);
    cv4.put(VARIANT_MODEL_ID, modelid);
    cv4.put(VARIANT_NAME, varname);
    cv4.put(VARIANT_POSTED_DATE, posteddate);
    return Database.insert(VARIANT_TABLE_NAME, null, cv4);
}
```

In the mainActivity,

```
for(int i = 0; i<build_emp_database.size();i++)
{                   
    md.createVariantEntry(build_emp_database.get(i).get(0), build_emp_database.get(i).get(1), build_emp_database.get(i).get(2), build_emp_database.get(i).get(3), build_emp_database.get(i).get(4));                                
}
```

Also, just for 2800 entries, it is taking more than a minute, is there any way to speed them up?? I have several small databases, and have loaded them successfully. This is the only big database and its creating an issue while inserting. Please help where am i going wrong.

Comment: For starters, you could assign `build_emp_database.get(i)` to a local variable in the `loop` and call the `get()` method so many times on that!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what do you mean by call the get() method so many times on that??

Comment: `build_emp_database.get(i).get(0)`, `build_emp_database.get(i).get(1)`, etc. This is the line I was referring to. Assign that `build_emp_database.get(i)` to a local variable say `myObj` and then call `myObj.get(0)`, `myObj.get(1)`, etc.

Comment: Instead of calling insert for 2800 times, which I think that is exactly the issue. I think you may try refer to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5009740/1131470, it teaches you how to insert multiple row at once. So do some logic, generate a string which is able to insert 2800 records at once, or portion by portion, minimizing the insert process. And yes, referring to Joe Malin, try to do it in AsyncTask.

Comment: Tried that, after 64 sec, its stops giving system error in the line create variantentry!

Comment: @Chor, this is for mysql, not sure if it works with sqlite, thanks for the reply, will try that as well!

Comment: Well if you read carefully it is actually about sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to run the insert operation on the UI thread, for starters.

I suggest you investigate using a content provider as a wrapper around your database. The ContentResolver object provides methods for doing operations in batch, and is in general a more robust way of working with databases. Use an IntentService to run the insert operation in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, both the create database and mainactivity are different java function. you suggest to run the insert using intentservice inside a asyntask?

Answer (score 1):

If you do a lot insert operation, you need use the `ContentProviderOperation` to optimize your db operation. like these:

```
 ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
     for(int i = 0; i<build_emp_database.size();i++) {
       ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = 
                 ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(yourUrl);
        builder.withValue(VARIANT_ID, varid)
               .withValue(VARIANT_MAKE_ID, makeid)
               ...
        ops.add(builder.build());
    }

     yourContentResolver.applyBatch(yourauthority, ops);
```